# Display category name based on selection else default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am displaying a list of gyms, and people can filter by province. This is working fine:

gym.rb

```
belongs_to: province
```

province.rb

```
has_many: gyms
```

gyms controller

```
def index
  if params[:province].blank?
    @gyms=Gym.all.order("created_at desc")
  else
    @province_id = Province.find_by(name: params[:province]).id
    @gyms = Gym.where(province_id: @province_id).order("created_at DESC")
  end
 end
```

In my gyms index view

```
<h2>All Facilities</h2>
```

I am wondering how I can show a different page title based on the province selected. If the category filter is clicked, I would like to display the selected province name instead.

Example, if Alberta is selected,

```
<h2>Alberta</h2>
```

Comment: What is category filter?

Comment: Not an answer but you can do this to simplify your code `@gyms = Province.find_by(...).gyms.order(created_at: :desc)`

Comment: @sawa Sorry I meant to say if they filter by province.

Comment: Still don't understand why negative though..some people out there misunderstood the question and...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do this

```
<h2>
  <%= (params[:province] || "All Facilities").titleize %>
</h2>
```

Comment: Thank you Md. Farhan Memon! Worked perfectly. Cheers.

Comment: @bgilbank Cheers.. :)